# store select result in variable and use in where condition

Tags: sql, firebird

A have 3 SQL queries that I put together using `union`.
The first 2 queries return unique Order ID's but the third query repeats Order ID's from the first 2.I need to exclude those results in query 3 .

Example:

```
QUERY 1:
SELECT DISTINCT
ORDER_ID,
PRODUCT
FROM
ORDERS
WHEN TYPE=A
```

query 1 sample data {12121212,13131313}

```
QUERY 2:
SELECT DISTINCT
ORDER_ID,
PRODUCT,
FROM
ORDERS
WHEN CATEGORY=X
```

Query 2 sample data {14141414,15151515}

```
QUERY 3:
SELECT DISTINCT
ORDER_ID,
PRODUCT
FROM    
ORDERS
WHEN TYPE=C
```

Query 3 sample data {17171717,12121212,14141414}

So query 3 repeats data from query 1 and 2. The real data is much larger. What I am trying to is to use the results of the first 2 queries to be excluded from query3

```
query1
union
query2
union
SELECT DISTINCT
ORDER_ID,
PRODUCT
FROM    
ORDERS
WHEN TYPE=C
AND
ORDER_ID NOT IN (Variable1=ORDER_ID IN QUERY1,Variable2=ORDER_ID IN QUERY2)
```

Desired data {12121212,13131313,14141414,15151515,16161616,17171717}

How can I store variables to use in the where condition ?

Appreciate any help

Comment: I don't get it.  The types are different, so the orders shouldn't overlap.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: HI Gordon,thank you for your reply. I have edited the question. Hope it is understandable now.

Comment: I don't understand the sample data. The third query only returns 2 columns but your sample data shows three values (=columns?) Or should that be three **rows**? If yes, what about the second column? Could you show us the sample data formatted as tables as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852)

Comment: The `PRODUCT` value for the `ORDER_ID` must be different in case you get duplicates as otherwise the UNION DISTINCT (which is the default) would do what you want. So how / which `PRODUCT` value to select when "deduping"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name those are obviously rows, for sure. So he wants to ignore second column when comparing, basically he wants a scheme like CSS - if payload value (here: Product) was returned by upper-tier source, ignore lesser-tier sources, otherwise fall through to lesser and lesser priorities sources until data found

Comment: But I can not tell why he has `DISTINCT` in all his partial queries. I thought ORDERID is already a primary key, if not then WHAT is the unique identifier, which columns subset?

Comment: @Arioch'The those can't be rows because then it would be one column per row, but all the queries select **two** columns - this "json notation" is highly confusing for tabular data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, the columns count and `distinct` confuses. But wearing my "user's helpdesk" hat I am guessing that he considers, albeit unable to word it, other columns as payload values to be returned by "order_id" key, and values differing for the same key form different sources

Comment: Where is `16161616` in your desired data coming form?

Answer (score 0):

It seems (but it is really hard to guess with any certainty) that you maybe want to do hierarchical data gathering, whether data is selected from 1st available source (from prioritized list), that has it, and next sources would get ignored.

Best of all I think would be making a persistent table having it all:

> ORDER_ID, PRODUCT, Source_Priority

Such a table would track up-to-date data from all the tables (for example by `AFTER UPADTE OR INSERT OR DELETE` trigger on `ORDERS` and other sources) and then your query would be reformulated as *"query new table, get rows with maximum-per-ORDER_ID-value-of-Source_Priority"*, which was asked many times, and is solved by one JOIN in Firebird 2 or by Window Functions in Firebird 3.

If you do not want to have a dedicated persistent prioritized table, You can do it, using

1. Global Temporary Table to do the sorting
   https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-tbl.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-gtt
2. `MERGE` command to do conditional inserts (clearing the table before it)
   https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-merge.html
3. `SELECT` to read the data from prepared GTT

If you want to pretend that would be one query, not 2+N, then you can hide them inside

4. a named `Stored Procedure` or an anonymous `EXECUTE BLOCK` https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-execblock.html

Something like that:

```
Create GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_ORDERS
( ORDER_ID integer PRIMARY KEY,
  PRODUCT VarChar(10) );
```

And then replace your "one true query" with this sequence (maybe hidden inside the Execution Block if need be)

```
DELETE FROM TMP_ORDERS;


INSERT INTO TMP_ORDERS
SELECT DISTINCT
ORDER_ID,
PRODUCT
FROM
ORDERS
WHEN TYPE=A;

MERGE INTO TMP_ORDERS as Dest
USING (
  SELECT DISTINCT
  ORDER_ID,
  PRODUCT,
  FROM
  ORDERS
  WHEN CATEGORY=X
) as Src
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(Dest.ORDER_ID, Dest.PRODUCT) VALUES(Src.ORDER_ID, Src.PRODUCT);

MERGE INTO TMP_ORDERS as Dest
USING (
  SELECT DISTINCT
  ORDER_ID,
  PRODUCT,
  FROM
  ORDERS
  WHEN TYPE=C) as Src
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(Dest.ORDER_ID, Dest.PRODUCT) VALUES(Src.ORDER_ID, Src.PRODUCT);

SELECT * FROM TMP_ORDERS;
```

P.S. but why did your partial queries even contained `DISTINCT` ? Isn't `ORDER_ID` already your `primary key` there, which can never be non-distinct, to start with?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
select * from
 (SELECT DISTINCT
  ORDER_ID,
  PRODUCT
  FROM
  ORDERS
  where TYPE='A') as q1,
 (SELECT DISTINCT
  ORDER_ID,
  PRODUCT
  FROM
  ORDERS
  WHERE CATEGORY='X'
  ) as q2,
 (SELECT DISTINCT
  ORDER_ID,
  PRODUCT
  FROM    
  ORDERS
  where  TYPE='C') as q3
 WHERE q1.order_id=q2.order_id
```